# Is there a way to find an Android element by partial resource ID in Appium using AnroidUIAutomator?

Tags: c#, android, appium, appium-android

I'm using Appium to automate some testing of an Android app and I'm looking for a way to find elements based on a partial resource ID match.

The app displays a number of notifications in a list. My code currently finds the first notification item shown on screen. I'm then trying to get the title from this item. The resource IDs for the notification tiles are of the form "notification-title-{6 digit ID}.

I'm attempting to search the notification item for resource IDs that match "notification-title-" which should give me the title element. However, I can't find any examples of how to do this.

My tests are written in c#.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can try with xpath

1. starts-with()
2. ends-with()
3. contains()

Comment: Thank you rakeshsahu59. Would you mind providing a code sample of contains()with a resource ID please? I'm not having any luck implementing it.

Comment: Try with  By.xpath("//*[contains(@resource-id, 'notification-title')]"); also, can you please send element details from screenshot.